# $A$ is invertible matrix, prove that $AA^t+A^tA$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A$ is invertible matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, prove that $AA^t+A^tA$ is invertible

It seems to be a trivial question, but it's not.
I tried using determinants, i.e $|A| \ne 0 \to |AA^t+A^tA|\ne0$, but calculating  $|AA^t+A^tA|$ is not easy.

Comment: Hint: If $B = AA^t+A^tA, v \neq 0$, show that $B$ is symmetric and that $v^TBv \neq 0$. Can you deduce from this that $B$ is invertible?

Comment: @πr8 This will show that B is positive-definite hence invertible, but how do I show that $v^tBv≠0$?

Comment: @πr8 Btw why not showing that $Bv \ne 0$ for $v \ne 0$ and that will show that 0 is not eigenvalueof B, hence B is invertible?

Comment: 1) Start by writing out what $v^TBv$ is, and see if you notice anything. 2) Because showing $Bv\neq0$ is actually harder - it's a similar idea, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $T$ (over $\mathbb C$, although perhaps not over $\mathbb R$). The entries of the main diagonal of $T$ are all non zero, since $A$ is invertible. The entries of both matrices $TT^t$ and $T^tT$ are the squares of the entries of the main diagonal of $T$, and therefore $TT^t+T^tT$ is an upper diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are all non zero. Therefore, it is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Both $AA^t$ and $A^tA$ are positive definite. Hence their sum is positive definite and invertible.